# How can we retrieve the upcoming facebook events that are located in a specific country(location)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I want to access the events listed all over FB in a specific location? By these events I mean the open events.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked several times in many channels before, but it seems that this is not possible. There is the Search API, but you can only search for even names: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Although, if there is a Facebook Page for the location, you can indeed grab the events:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

```
/[page-id]/events
```

This works even without any Access Token (if the page is not hidden, of course).